# Read/Write to command-line .exe Java

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I'm trying to launch a process in java, read the output, write to the program, then read what it responds with.  From all the other answers on SO, this is what I have come up with:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "";
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\myProgram.exe");
            Process p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            output.write("foo");
            output.newLine();
            output.flush();

            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            p.destroy();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
        }
    }
}
```

It launches the program, and gives me the output just as expected.

When i write `foo`, I expect the program to come back with another response, but it never does.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this could help you ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433073/how-to-write-into-and-read-from-command-line-in-java

Comment: How many lines are you trying to read? `readline()` will read until it runs out - maybe just call it once?