# Close windows command line -cmd

Tags: java, cmd

How to close opened windows command line?
I started in cmd server for reporting tests and i have info about:

> "Starting web server... Press 'Ctrl+C' to exit"

How to send "ctrl+c" and close cmd in java?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, do you want to send a ctrl+c equivalent signal to the Command (cmd) application  in Windows to process and then close the Command window from your java program? I don't think it is possible at all.

Comment: I would like to close cmd but I can't do it without press ctr+c.
How to close/kill cmd window?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the PID of this Process and then destroy it
this might help you

[The right way to kill a process in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230507/the-right-way-to-kill-a-process-in-java/35230678)

[Kill a process based on PID in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573696/kill-a-process-based-on-pid-in-java)

Comment: can you explain more why its not woking?
if you want to close cmd

       String cmd = "taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Comment: I have information "Starting web server... Press 'Ctrl+C' to exit". If use "taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe" nothing will happen. But if I manually press ctrl+c on cmd then I can use "taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe" ad close cmd.

Comment: Well, you can write a Code  in java to open cmd and run the server you want then terminat it and close it when you want.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433073/how-to-write-into-and-read-from-command-line-in-java

and insted of sending Ctrl+C you can write "kill -SIGINT processPIDHere"

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: `"taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe"` that will close cmd.exe. You were supposed to provide name of application you want to kill.