# How i can build app that based on extension concept?

Tags: java, python

I need to write module and install it in the program after compile and run it without make recompile .

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to start the other executable in a separate process.

This question might provide some insight into doing that:

[Java external program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335698/java-external-program)